# Giving a method for generating random numbers with a cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, generating-functions

So let's say I have a [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function):

$$F(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x + x^2)  \space for \space 0 \lt x \lt 1$$

How do I find a method for generating random numbers from this function?

Comment: There are many ways. For example, let $U$ be uniform on $[0,1]$ (many computer programs produce pseudo-random "numbers" that have this distribution). Then $F^{-1}(U)$ has the distribution you are interested in.

Comment: So I did find F^-1 of my function, which gives me  1/2 * (-1 +- sqrt(8y+1)), would that be my final answer?

Comment: The relevant inverse is $\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8y}}{2}$. (The "minus" choice gives negatives, wrong half of the parabola.) The answer would depend on the wording you use in your course. If we call the inverse $G(y)$, then one might say that we use a pseudo-random number generator that simulates a uniform on $[0,1]$, and the number $u$ is generated, then $G(u)$ would be our pseudo-observation  for the random variable $X$ that has cumulative distribution $F(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate mode of generation that is rather natural as well.

Consider a random variable $X$ that has $F$ as its cdf. By definition of a cdf, one can write, for $0 < x \leq 1$:

$$P(X<x)=\dfrac{1}{2}x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 \ \ \ (1)$$

We know that $F_1(x)=x$ is the cdf of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ (abbreviated as u.d.), and we may know that $F_2(x)=x^2$ is the cdf of the maximum of 2 u.d. (always with the assumption $0 < x \leq 1$).

Consider thus the random variable $Y$ that is built in two steps:

- a Bernoulli $B_1 \equiv Ber(1/2)$ is drawn.
- if $B_1=0$, set $Y=R_1$ where $R_1$ is u.d.
- else (if $B_1=1$) set $Y=\max(R_1,R_2)$ where $R_2$ is u.d.

If we analyze

$$P(Y<y)=P(Y<y\mid B_1=0)P(B_1=0)+P(Y<y\mid B_1=1)P(B_1=1)$$

$$P(Y<y)=P(R_1<y)\frac{1}{2}+P(\max(R_1,R_2)<y)\frac{1}{2}$$

$$P(Y<y)=y\frac{1}{2}+y^2\frac{1}{2} \ \ \ (2)$$

which coincides with (1)

We can simulate this in the following way in Matlab:

```
for k=1:100000
if rand<0.5
t(k)=rand;
else t(k)=max([rand,rand]);
end
end
hist(t)
```